# Firefox and HTTP/2 server push

Tags: firefox, http2, server-push

HTTP/2 server push makes our sites considerably faster on first view. However, Firefox seems to have disabled server push since ca. v56.

Over at webpagetest.org, Patrick Meenan suggested that the developers had turned this off temporarily. Searching the web, I could not find any confirmation or info on this. But almost half a year later, our sites still load considerably slower in Firefox than in e.g. Chrome and this is clearly due to Firefox not accepting server push.

Does anyone know if and when server push will come back to Firefox?

Comment: Firefox v56 shipped with a bug in HTTP/2 push that would prevent page loads when push was enabled. https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1409570 tracks the bug, the fix is scheduled for v58. Not posting this as an answer since i haven't been able to track down the push disabling in firefox release notes.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I had searched Mozilla's Bugzilla but could not find this issue. Great to see that server push will come back to FF...

Comment: on FF 98 on linux still not working